# town, village, prefecture shapefiles for China?

Tags: shapefile, data, china

I'm looking for boundary files for towns, villages and prefectures in China that are free. I've came across http://chinadataonline.org/, but they are limited.

Can anyone tell me where to look?

Comment: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/ will get you some of it. Towns and villages often don't have well defined boundaries.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I did find that site after more searching. I also found http://www.gadm.org/ which is helpful.

Comment: The correct link for the Global Administrative Database is: www.gadm.org/country

Comment: Was gadm.org helpful? The boundaries are unclear, it did not even have district boundaries for province level cities

Answer (score 1):

There is the Global Administrative Database:
https://gadm.org/download_country.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen or checked DIVA-GIS that they have China boundary ?

http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

Though this site does not have any GIS layers but it has the information about China : http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/china.htm  They have put up maps that may help you to locate towns,Villages and etc..

GeoNetwork has another one for China as well http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home